# In Eclipse how to get web application published to JBoss Home instead of plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I have **JBoss 6.1.0.Final** installed in `D:\Programs\jboss-as-distribution-6.1.0.Final` folder.

I have Eclipse Kepler installed in `D:\Programs\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-win32` folder.

For Eclipse Kepler my Workspace is `D:\Workspaces\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-win32` folder.

In Eclipse I created a **New Server Runtime Environment** for JBoss 6.x Runtime. The Home Directory was `D:\Programs\jboss-as-distribution-6.1.0.Final` and server was "default".

I then add my web application to it.

Now whenever I publish my web application to this server, it goes to this folder `D:\Workspaces\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-win32\.metadata\.plugins\org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core\JBoss_6.x_Runtime_Server1431035626713\deploy`.

What I want instead is eclipse to publish my web application to `D:\Programs\jboss-as-distribution-6.1.0.Final\server\default\deploy` folder.

How can I do that?